# Getting style attribute using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a page and from a table on that page I'm getting all `<tr>` elements like so:

```
r = requests.get("http://lol.esportswikis.com/wiki/G2_Esports/Match_History")
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
tr = s.find_all("table", class_="wikitable sortable")[0].find_all("tr")[3:]

print tr[0]
```

which outputs:

```
<tr style="background-color:#C6EFCE"><td>...</td> ... <td>...</td></tr>
```

Now I'm trying to get the style of the `<tr>` tag, but I have no idea how. If I do this for example:

```
for item in tr[0]:
    print item
```

it obviously just prints the `<td> ... </td>` stuff. I'm thinking I can probably do something like `print tr[0].something`, like `tr[0].tag`, but everything I've tried so far hasn't resulted in what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just access the attribute using `tag["attribute"]`:

```
In [28]: soup = BeautifulSoup('<tr style="pretty"></tr>', 'html.parser')

In [29]: print(soup.find("tr")["style"]) 
pretty
```

If you only want the tr tags with style attributes an to get them all:

```
trs = s.find("table", class_="example-table").find_all("tr", style=True)

for tr in trs:
    print(tr["style"])
```

Or using a css selector:

```
trs = s.select("table.example-table tr[style]")

for tr in trs:
    print(tr["style"])
```

Using your actual url:

```
In [41]: r = requests.get("http://lol.esportswikis.com/wiki/G2_Esports/Match_History")

In [42]: s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

In [43]: trs = s.select("table.wikitable.sortable tr[style]")

In [44]: 

In [44]: for tr in trs:
   ....:         print(tr["style"])
   ....:     
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#FFC7CE
background-color:#C6EFCE
```

Comment: No worries, I added the output using the css select, find_all will do exactly the same