# Python BeautifulSoup StyleTag Extract

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the text '64%' from the below code on the web page using Python and BeautifulSoup, please help.

```
<span class="textword" style="width:64%">BUY</span>
```

Regards,babsdoc

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843903/getting-style-of-tr-tag-using-beautifulsoup

Comment: Thanks ! Got the answer from the thread you posted TrakJohnson !

Comment: No problem, in the future before asking anything on SO please do a [minimum of googling](https://www.google.fr/search?q=get+style+beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='<span class="textword" style="width:64%">BUY</span>'
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

#if you have only one such element:
needed_text = soup.find('span', {'style':'width:64%'}).text

#if you have many elements to scrape:
needed_text = []
needed_text_tags = soup.find_all('span', {'style':'width:64%'})
for i in needed_text_tags:
    needed_text.append(i.text)
```