# can you scrape a changing color from a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping some values from a website using `beautifulSoup`, and it worked to scrape the numbers, only I can't scrape the background color from the numbers. (the background color changes with the value and is very important)

https://www.windguru.cz/station/219

this is the page and I want to scrape the color from the wind.

```py
page = requests.get('https://www.windguru.cz/station/219')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all("div",{''})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting style of <tr> tag using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843903/getting-style-of-tr-tag-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @G.Anderson no, because when I try that, I don't get a value, because on the site I use, the color is changing every minute....

Comment: I see a lot of lines, numbers and colours. It would help if you indicated which you were after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a raw HTTP request environment, you're only gathering the HTML that's sent back by the server. Thus if the page is rendering new data constantly, you'll need a headless browser to observe those changes. You can tell that the data is being rendered in this page because observing the *page source* of the website varies from the source that you see if you "inspect element" on the page.

When you are using Python to request the page source, you're only getting the 'skeleton' HTML and rendering scripts, but not the actual rendered data.

Looks like this page constantly pings a PHP script every ~20 seconds to gather new chart data. Then it's using JavaScript to interpret that data and parse it into a visible chart... looks like it's using SVG to display the path data.

Here is the data as a response from the PHP script, which we can find by watching the "network" tab on the web inspector:

`https://www.windguru.cz/int/iapi.php?q=station_data_current&id_station=219&date_format=Y-m-d%20H%3Ai%3As%20T&_mha=f4d18b6c`

```
{
    "wind_avg": 6.99,
    "wind_max": 8.93,
    "wind_min": 4.85,
    "wind_direction": 171.215,
    "temperature": 13,
    "mslp": null,
    "rh": null,
    "datetime": "2019-06-12 23:08:17 CEST",
    "unixtime": 1560373697
}
```

You have 2 options here:

1) Use a headless browser like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), [NightmareJS](http://www.nightmarejs.org/), [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), etc. to render the live version of the site and gather data once the chart has rendered. This would be the simpler answer, and the one I would recommend. Headless browsers do have a downside of using more memory when running, so if this is a solution that needs to be scaled up then this could be problematic.

2) Gather the live data directly from the server by sending a request to the link above, then interpret it based on on the colors it correlates to. This is probably the most complicated solution, but if using a headless browser is out of the question this is what you'll have to do. You'll have to read through the JavaScript that the page is using to 'colorize' the data and mimic it yourself in Python.