# Write into csv file in row parsed several css style in html

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing html with css style in tags.

```
<table class="cmp-ratings-expanded">
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 60.0%;"></span>
<td>Job Work</td>
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 80.0%;"></span>
<td>Compensation</td>
</table>

<table class="cmp-ratings-expanded">
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 100.0%;"></span>
<td>Job Work</td>
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 40.0%;"></span>
<td>Compensation</td>
</table>
```

I need to get these: 60, 80, 100, 40 numbers in order to write to csv

I have tried

```
rates = soup.find_all('table', {'class':['cmp-ratings-expanded']}).find_all("span", style=True)
for rate in rates:
    rate = re.match( r'width: (\d+)', rate["style"])
```

from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843954/10436029), but found that I'm parsing only 60, 80 numbers. All the left `numbers (100, 40)` not parsed due to **find()** method of Beautiful Soup.

Ultimately, I need to write to csv file.
Here the result I got from above code due to for loop:

```
|60|
|100|
```

Code to write into csv:

```
with open(some_file.csv, 'w+') as file:
     file.write(rate)
```

#### What I expect.

Parse all the *width: **80**.0%;* like style information to be written into csv in row:

```
|Job Work|Compensation|
|60|80|
|100|40|
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS selectors to parse the HTML:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<table class="cmp-ratings-expanded">
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 60.0%;"></span>
<td>Job Work</td>
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 80.0%;"></span>
<td>Compensation</td>
</table>

<table class="cmp-ratings-expanded">
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 100.0%;"></span>
<td>Job Work</td>
<span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 40.0%;"></span>
<td>Compensation</td>
</table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
r_number = re.compile(r'(\d+)\.?\d*%')

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write('|Job Work|Compensation|\n')
    for job, compensation in zip(soup.select('span[style]:has(+:contains("Job Work"))'),
                                 soup.select('span[style]:has(+:contains("Compensation"))')):
        job_number = r_number.search(job['style'])[1]
        compensation_number = r_number.search(compensation['style'])[1]
        f_out.write('|' + '|'.join([job_number, compensation_number]) + '|\n')
```

The file `out.csv` contains:

```
|Job Work|Compensation|
|60|80|
|100|40|
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<table class="cmp-ratings-expanded">
    <span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 60.0%;"></span>
        <td>Job Work</td>
            <span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 80.0%;"></span>
        <td>Compensation</td>
    </table>

    <table class="cmp-ratings-expanded">
    <span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 100.0%;"></span>
    <td>Job Work</td>
    <span class="cmp-Rating-on" style="width: 40.0%;"></span>
    <td>Compensation</td>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class':['cmp-ratings-expanded']})
result = []
for table in tables:
    temp = []
    for span in table.find_all("span", style=True):
        rate = re.match( r'width: (\d+)', span["style"])  
        temp.append(rate.group(1))                       #Get Rates. 
    result.append(temp)

#Write to CSV
with open(filename, "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="|")
    #Write Header
    writer.writerow(["Job Work", "Compensation"])
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Comment: I didn't show all the code, so I could not integrate your suggestion into my many columns csv file.