# How to get a style value inside a span tag with a python scraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I downloaded the code of this website: https://www.ilmakiage.co.il/mineral-lip-pencil-4040 with the response.get method. In the inspectors mode I could see that there was a style value "display: block;" or "display: none;" in a unique span class="qtyValidate_color" tag I wanted to download. But when I opened my soup or response.text I couldn't find that value in that span tag. It's empty. Please let me know what library or method I can use to get this style value in the span tag.

My Python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.ilmakiage.co.il/mineral-lip-pencil-4043')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

no_quantity = soup.find('span', class_='qtyValidate_color').contents[0]

if no_quantity == 'הכמות המבוקשת אינה קיימת':
    print("Ooops, 'הכמות המבוקשת אינה קיימת' the stock is empty. Open the app later. You will see the 'Shopping time' phrase when the lipstick be in stock")
else:
    print('Shopping time')
```

HTML code on the website in Chrome inspector mode

```
<span class="qtyValidate_color" style="display: block;">הכמות המבוקשת אינה קיימת</span>
<span class="qtyValidate_color" style="display: none;">הכמות המבוקשת אינה קיימת</span>
```

Screenshot:
[Website code in Inspector mode Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh9u6.jpg)

lXML code in my soup

```
<span class="qtyValidate_color">הכמות המבוקשת אינה קיימת</span>
```

Screenshot 2:
[Website code lxml in my soup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9v2L.jpg)

I tried reading stackoverflow and replacing request.get method with urllib3 methods

ps. i'm doing data analysis course now and created this tool for my girlfriend as a part of my training.

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect the page source, the span element appears the same as in your soup (and your code works for me as I would expect it to).

[image]

It may be that the element appears differently on different devices, or if logged in, for example.

You can include style in your search with `attr={'style': 'my_style'}`, for example, on that url:

```
example = soup.find('span', class_='show_sku', attrs={'style': 'display:none'})
```

Comment: Damian, thanks for your answer. The issue that in inspector node on chrome I see the <span class="qtyValidate_color" style="display: block;">הכמות המבוקשת אינה קיימת</span> and I want to srape style="display: block; for my program. But in my soup that style="display: block; disappears. And I was wondering why and how to keep this style value in my soup. Maybe you have something in your mind for this? I added two screenshots above comparing inspectors mode and soup to make it  more clear.

Comment: @RomaShakshuka probably the in-line style is added once the page is fully loaded. Try to check if there is a javascript code that points to the element with `qtyValidate_color` class. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843954/12511801) as well.